# Can a tbody be inside another one?

Tags: html

Is it possible to have an inner tbody inside an outer tbody like this:

here is a sample css:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .class1 {background-color:#ff0000;}
    .class2 {background-color:#00ff00;}
  </style>
```

Here is the sample HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody id="outer" class="class1">
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="inner" class="class2">
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody> <!-- inner -->
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> <!-- outer -->
</table>
```

My purpose is to apply class1 CSS to the outer tbody and class2 to the inner tbody.
But the last TR is consider to be out of the outer tbody as I want it to be inside the outer tbody.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

While this may work in practice, [it is not legal HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3).

However, you are allowed to have multiple TBODY elements in a single TABLE element, so you could do this:

```
<table> 
  <tbody class="show"> 
    <tr> 
      <td>...</td> 
      <td>...</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hide"> 
    <tr> 
      <td>...</td> 
      <td>...</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="show"> 
    <tr> 
      <td>...</td> 
      <td>...</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you may be able to nest tables, although I wouldn't really recommend that.

Comment: But I have the example and it's work https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/gaGBZz. Maybe you can help me, and change this structure of html to correct, but it's should work as it worked before. I'll so appreciate you.

Answer (score 19):

The way would be to create another table and use `tbody` afterwards:

```
<table>
  <tbody id="outer" class="show">
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
         <table>
        <tbody id="inner" class="hide">
         <tr>
           <td>...</td>
           <td>...</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody> <!-- inner -->
         </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> <!-- outer -->
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but ihave preference for Michael Madsen's answer.

Comment: this was the correct answer to the original question, because it allows tbody elements within tbody elements which was what was asked for. This allows to select by parent tbody id and child tbody class if need be.

Comment: This answer may be formally correct, but it's meaningless. The tbodies will belong to different tables, so their columns won't be aligned with each other.

Answer (score 9):

Nope, this is [not possible](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY). According to the spec, the `TBODY` element can contain only `TR` elements.

```
<!ELEMENT TBODY    O O (TR)+           -- table body -->
```

what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't do such thing.

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) a tbody can't inside another one.

Answer (score 1):

Not likely. If all you want is to 'distinguish' some set of rows, I would assign class `inner` to each row in question (instead of `tbody`). Then you easily manipulate those rows with any js framework, like `$('tr.inner').show();`.